# Error while working with json and ajax, struts2

Tags: java, ajax, json, struts2

I am getting while trying to fetch data using ajax and jquery with json `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.LoggerFactory.` So i loaded with xwork-2.1.1.jar.Then i am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.setContext(DefaultConfiguration.java:203)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:171).
```

How to resolve this issue?

following are the my struts and xwork jar versions? How do i find exact jar versions.?
`struts2-core-j4-2.0.14.jar`
`struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar`
`struts2-tiles-plugin-2.0.11.1-j4.jar`
`xwork-j4-2.0.7.jar`

Comment: Please include which versions of everything you're using.

Comment: Well, I actually meant the Struts/XWork stuff. Plus I can't see that. Easier to cut-and-paste actual text. In any case, the tiny bits I can make out indicate you're using essentially random versions of the struts 2 stuff--really bad idea. Use jars from a single version.

Comment: @Jothi:How you picked up the jars? they seems a bit doubtful to me as the version is not consistent.Not sure this can be an issue.Better use same version for all required jars don't mix them up

Comment: How do you solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

In my minimal Struts2.2.3 project, I include the following jars :

```
struts2-core-2.2.3.jar
xwork-core-2.2.3.jar
freemarker-2.3.16.jar
ognl-3.0.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-commons-3.1.jar
javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
```

In my minimal Struts2.1.8 project, I include the following jars :

```
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
freemarker-2.3.15.jar
ognl-2.7.3.jar
struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
xwork-core-2.1.6.jar
```